# Keep Getting MySQL error of 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111

Tags: mysql, linux

I know this is a common issue. But I shut the DB server down with the Unix "service mysqld stop" command then restarted the server soon after with the "service mysqld start" command. I did it to flush out a couple of "killed" MySQL processes.
Checking, I get the 
service mysqld status
mysqld (pid  19354) is running...
But on my webpages that access the DB I get the error "The Database Connection Is Down: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111"
So all I did was shut the DB server down and started it up again a minute later. How long will the problem persist, or is there more I should do?

Answer (score 0):

Your host is wrong, your port is wrong, a firewall blocked the connection, or the SQL server is not running. 111 is "connection refused". You can troubleshoot by trying to telnet to the SQL server's host and port. If that works, your code gets the host or port wrong.

If that doesn't work, check on the SQL server itself. If it works there, the problem is the network. If it doesn't work there, the SQL server is not running.

Be sure the mysql is running: `service mysqld status` or try with PHPmyadmin